# what is the fastest way to get the mode of a numpy array

Tags: numpy, scipy

I have to find the mode of a NumPy array that I read from an hdf5 file.  The NumPy array is 1d and contains floating point values.

```
my_array=f1[ds_name].value    
mod_value=scipy.stats.mode(my_array)
```

My array is 1d and contains around 1M values. It takes about 15 min for my script to return the mode value. Is there any way to make this faster?

Another question is why `scipy.stats.median(my_array)` does not work while mode works?

> **AttributeError: module 'scipy.stats' has no attribute 'median'**

Comment: Sounds IO-bound as the remaining code is optimal in my opinion. So check your hdf; buffers, compression and co. Also: scipy.stats does not have a function called median, easily checked by reading the docs. You can just use numpy's median.

Comment: @sascha The  file is read in 0.02 seconds. The 15 min time is spent in calculating the mode in this line of code "scipy.stats.median(my_array)".

Comment: Maybe you should show more code as your timings differ a lot from these synthetic examples shown in the given answers (which also showed i was wrong; there are not-that-hard-to-implement speedups achievable).

Comment: @sascha please check the added reply for complete code. please let me know if you need my input file for testing, thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The implementation of `scipy.stats.mode` has a Python loop for handling the `axis` argument with multidimensional arrays.  The following simple implementation, for one-dimensional arrays only, is faster:

```
def mode1(x):
    values, counts = np.unique(x, return_counts=True)
    m = counts.argmax()
    return values[m], counts[m]
```

Here's an example.  First, make an array of integers with length 1000000.

```
In [40]: x = np.random.randint(0, 1000, size=(2, 1000000)).sum(axis=0)

In [41]: x.shape
Out[41]: (1000000,)
```

Check that `scipy.stats.mode` and `mode1` give the same result.

```
In [42]: from scipy.stats import mode

In [43]: mode(x)
Out[43]: ModeResult(mode=array([1009]), count=array([1066]))

In [44]: mode1(x)
Out[44]: (1009, 1066)
```

Now check the performance.

```
In [45]: %timeit mode(x)
2.91 s ± 18 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [46]: %timeit mode1(x)
39.6 ms ± 83.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

2.91 seconds for `mode(x)` and only 39.6 milliseconds for `mode1(x)`.

Comment: Just for kicks I gave this a try with `Counter`.  The runtime is about half that of `scs.mode` but your solution takes the cake easily.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach based on sorting -

```
def mode1d(ar_sorted):
    ar_sorted.sort()
    idx = np.flatnonzero(ar_sorted[1:] != ar_sorted[:-1])
    count = np.empty(idx.size+1,dtype=int)
    count[1:-1] = idx[1:] - idx[:-1]
    count[0] = idx[0] + 1
    count[-1] = ar_sorted.size - idx[-1] - 1
    argmax_idx = count.argmax()

    if argmax_idx==len(idx):
        modeval = ar_sorted[-1]
    else:
        modeval = ar_sorted[idx[argmax_idx]]
    modecount = count[argmax_idx]
    return modeval, modecount
```

Note that this mutates/changes the input array as it sorts it. So, if you want to keep the input array *un-mutated* or do mind the input array being sorted, pass a copy.

Sample run on 1M elements -

```
In [65]: x = np.random.randint(0, 1000, size=(1000000)).astype(float)

In [66]: from scipy.stats import mode

In [67]: mode(x)
Out[67]: ModeResult(mode=array([ 295.]), count=array([1098]))

In [68]: mode1d(x)
Out[68]: (295.0, 1098)
```

**Runtime test**

```
In [75]: x = np.random.randint(0, 1000, size=(1000000)).astype(float)

# Scipy's mode
In [76]: %timeit mode(x)
1 loop, best of 3: 1.64 s per loop

# @Warren Weckesser's soln
In [77]: %timeit mode1(x)
10 loops, best of 3: 52.7 ms per loop

# Proposed in this post
In [78]: %timeit mode1d(x)
100 loops, best of 3: 12.8 ms per loop
```

With a copy, the timings for `mode1d` would be comparable to `mode1`.

Answer (score 0):

I added the two functions mode1 and mode1d from replies above to my script and tried to compare with the scipy.stats.mode.

```
dir_name="C:/Users/test_mode"
file_name="myfile2.h5"
ds_name="myds"
f_in=os.path.join(dir_name,file_name)

def mode1(x):
    values, counts = np.unique(x, return_counts=True)
    m = counts.argmax()
    return values[m], counts[m]

def mode1d(ar_sorted):
    ar_sorted.sort()
    idx = np.flatnonzero(ar_sorted[1:] != ar_sorted[:-1])
    count = np.empty(idx.size+1,dtype=int)
    count[1:-1] = idx[1:] - idx[:-1]
    count[0] = idx[0] + 1
    count[-1] = ar_sorted.size - idx[-1] - 1
    argmax_idx = count.argmax()

    if argmax_idx==len(idx):
        modeval = ar_sorted[-1]
    else:
        modeval = ar_sorted[idx[argmax_idx]]
    modecount = count[argmax_idx]
    return modeval, modecount


startTime=time.time()
with h5py.File(f_in, "a") as f1:

        myds=f1[ds_name].value
        time1=time.time()
        file_read_time=time1-startTime
        print(str(file_read_time)+"\t"+"s"+"\t"+str((file_read_time)/60)+"\t"+"min")

        print("mode_scipy=")
        mode_scipy=scipy.stats.mode(myds)
        print(mode_scipy)
        time2=time.time()
        mode_scipy_time=time2-time1
        print(str(mode_scipy_time)+"\t"+"s"+"\t"+str((mode_scipy_time)/60)+"\t"+"min")

        print("mode1=")
        mode1=mode1(myds)
        print(mode1)
        time3=time.time()
        mode1_time=time3-time2
        print(str(mode1_time)+"\t"+"s"+"\t"+str((mode1_time)/60)+"\t"+"min")

        print("mode1d=")
        mode1d=mode1d(myds)
        print(mode1d)
        time4=time.time()
        mode1d_time=time4-time3
        print(str(mode1d_time)+"\t"+"s"+"\t"+str((mode1d_time)/60)+"\t"+"min")
```

The result from running the script for a numpy array of around 1M is  :

mode_scipy=
ModeResult(mode=array([  1.11903353e-06], dtype=float32), count=array([304909]))
938.8368742465973   s
**15.647281237443288    min**

mode1=(1.1190335e-06, 304909)

0.06500649452209473 s
0.0010834415753682455   min

mode1d=(1.1190335e-06, 304909)

0.06200599670410156 s
0.0010334332784016928   min